# How to build a GraphQL API with api-platform?

Tags: api, graphql, api-platform.com

When I entered in [api-platform website](https://api-platform.com/) I saw "REST and GraphQL framework to build modern API-driven projects". 
But I didn't find any documentation which explain how to generate GraphQL API's in api-platform. 
Can anyone confirm me if it's possible and how to do that ?

Comment: Here is the answer : https://github.com/api-platform/docs/blob/master/core/graphql.md

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GraphQL is a pretty new thing in API Platform. Please have a look at version 2.2.

Here are some useful resources:

- [docs](https://github.com/api-platform/docs/blob/2.2/core/graphql.md)
- [blog post about 2.2 release](https://dunglas.fr/2018/01/api-platform-2-2-graphql-json-api-admin-and-pwa-kubernetes-instant-deployment-and-many-more-new-features)
- [PR - GraphQL: add support for filters](https://github.com/api-platform/core/pull/1633)
- [PR - GraphQL + data provider refactoring: automatically add SQL join clauses](https://github.com/api-platform/core/pull/1619)
- [PR - Add validation for GraphQL mutations](https://github.com/api-platform/core/pull/1604)
- [PR - GraphQL: honor access control rules](https://github.com/api-platform/core/pull/1602)
- [PR - Implement the Relay specification for mutations](https://github.com/api-platform/core/pull/1597)

As the time goes on I believe there will be more resources on the official docs.

Comment: Thanks a lot for providing me these informations mheki !